# Launch top command showing all cores immediately

Tags: terminal, top

I know that once you run `top` if you press <kbd>1</kbd> you can see the load on each processor (let's forget the multi-threading issue) and if you press <kbd>s</kbd> you can configure the refresh time.

How can I put this options in the launch command?

I am trying to log the output with

```
$ top -b -p $(pidof myprocess) > top.log
```

But I want to see my four processors and a higher refresh rate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Linux `top` has support for a configuration file (`~/.toprc`) which it can also write from running configuration:

- start `top`
- enable the options you want (colors, update frequency, sort order, statistics displayed, ...)
- hit `W` (that is, shift+w)

Next time you run `top`, it will read your configuration and change its defaults to what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

The `top manpage` shows the `Startup Defaults` that are configurable from the `commandline`.  The `Cpu` display is not one of them.

```
   Startup Defaults
   The following startup defaults assume no configuration file, thus no user customizations.  Even so, items shown with an asterisk (’*’) could be overridden  through  the  command-
   line.

       Global_defaults
          ’A’ - Alt display      Off (full-screen)
        * ’d’ - Delay time       3.0 seconds
          ’I’ - Irix mode        On  (no, ’solaris’ smp)
        * ’p’ - PID monitoring   Off
        * ’s’ - Secure mode      Off (unsecured)
          ’B’ - Bold disable     Off
       Summary_Area_defaults
          ’l’ - Load Avg/Uptime  On  (thus program name)
          ’t’ - Task/Cpu states  On  (1+1 lines, see ’1’)
          ’m’ - Mem/Swap usage   On  (2 lines worth)
          ’1’ - Single Cpu       On  (thus 1 line if smp)
       Task_Area_defaults
          ’b’ - Bold hilite      On  (not ’reverse’)
        * ’c’ - Command line     Off (name, not cmdline)
        * ’H’ - Threads          Off (show all threads)
        * ’i’ - Idle tasks       On  (show all tasks)
          ’R’ - Reverse sort     On  (pids high-to-low)
        * ’S’ - Cumulative time  Off (no, dead children)
          ’x’ - Column hilite    Off (no, sort field)
          ’y’ - Row hilite       On  (yes, running tasks)
          ’z’ - color/mono       Off (no, colors)
```

This can be accomplished using a `top` configuration file.  From the `top manpage`:

```
   5b. PERSONAL Configuration File
   This file is written as ’$HOME/.your-name-4-top’ + ’rc’.  Use the ’W’ interactive command to create it or update it.
```

Steps to create Configuration file that starts `top` showing all processors:

```
1. Start `top`.
2. Toggle display of all CPUs (press 1).
3. Press `d` or `s` and set new delay (default=3.0 seconds).  (This can be set on the `commandline`.  See the `Startup Defaults` above.
4. Press Shift+W.  Notice message 'Wrote configuration to '/home/youruser/.toprc'.
5. Quit `top`.
6. Start `top`.  Until you rewrite the `top` configuration file with a different option (Step #3), it will start with all CPUs showing.
```