# Opening top with interactive interface option

Tags: top, suse

On a SUSE Linux Enteprise 12 system, I'm trying to out the `top` command + the interactive interface option 1 but can't seem to figure out how to 'send' the 1 option.

The 1 option gives you an overview of the cpu usage per cpu (or thread)

top -1 does not work

I can't image this not being possible but I can't seem to find the solution. Can this be distro specific?

Comment: Is this for a GNU/Linux system? If so, have you considered the ~/.toprc config file option?

Comment: I'm using SUSE Linux Enterprise 12

Comment: @JeffSchaller Thank you. When top was open and I enabled the option then I pressed W, this creates the ~/.toprc config file as suggested.

Comment: That "solves" the problem for future `top` calls, but I wasn't sure if it was an Answer to your question, since it sounded like you wanted to be able to pass various interactive options while calling top...?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Launch top command showing all cores immediately](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256377/launch-top-command-showing-all-cores-immediately)